# Open cart display all products without paginations

Tags: php, opencart

Is it possible that i can display all the product list without pagination in the open cart ? If yes then how can i?
I am using Version 2.0.1.1

Comment: What Opencart version are you using?

Comment: i am using Opencart Version 2.0.1.1

Comment: in admin or front end ?

Comment: i would like to have it at Front side . .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only need to edit **Default Items Per Page** setting in *Admin > Settings > Option* tab. Set it to a high value.

**UPDATE:**

I don't think you need to write an extension to handle that, try this:

Set default items per page to, say 999, then in relevant templates such as *C:\xampp\htdocs\oc2101\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.tpl*
after line:

```
<?php if ($limits['value'] == $limit) { ?>
```

Add

```
 <?php 
 $limits['text'] = ($limits['text'] == '999') ? 'Show All' : $limits['text'];
  ?>
```

You'll get *Show all* option in your select for pagination instead of *999*

Of course, it'll need a bit more work if you need muilti-language support, but this is just an idea of a quick fix.

Comment: Actually what i want to do is, i also want to keep the the pagination on ,
i am going to give a a "View all" button on a page , i am also ready to create a separate controller / model / view if require. But any how i want to list out all the products without the pagination.